# Can you insert a string literal that contains unicode (like a Chinese character) into a Jinja2 template?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, unicode, jinja2

In my Python code (.py file), I set a session variable to Chinese characters:

`session.mystring = '你好'`

At first, Flask choked. So, at the very top of the file, I put:

`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

That solved the problem. I could then display the string in my Flask app by just doing:

`{{ session.mystring }}`

Here's the weird problem. If I write the Chinese characters directly into the template (.html file), like so:

```
  <!-- this works -->  
<p>{{ session.mystring }}</p>

  <!-- this doesn't -->  
<p>你好</p>
```

The browser (Edge) displays the following error:

'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 516: invalid start byte

I tried putting the following at the top of the template:

```
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
```

But that doesn't help. Is there any way I can insert the Chinese characters directly as a literal in the Jinja2 template?

EDIT (June 7, 2020):
Made my question clearer by actually putting the Chinese characters into the question (thought I couldn't previously).

Answer (score 0):

This should work , by simply adding below in HTML file:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

[working eg here :](https://codepen.io/codeITNewbie/pen/XWXbmER)

**with minimal flask app:**

**app.py:**

from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(**name**)

```
@app.route('/')
def test():
    data = '中华人民共和国'
    return render_template('index.html', data=data)

if(__name__) == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**In templates/index.html :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    {{ data }}
</body>

</html>
```

**o/p:**

[image]

Comment: Yes, this works, but this is not my question. Instead of writing {{data}}, I'm trying to write:
<body>你好</body> in the HTML file. Sorry if my question wasn't clear.

Comment: @MucusPigboy Hey I have added the same using a `<p>` for sample in the link ...May be you are looking for this https://codepen.io/codeITNewbie/pen/XWXbmER  i have added this in my answer too :)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I wanted to test to make sure. Your stuff DEFINITELY works. I found out that my problem is that my editor didn't save the file as a UTF-8 file. Thanks - have given you an upvote!